# How do I put a cover on for a youtube video?

Tags: video, html5-video

I have a video and i want it upload on my site like we uploads embed video. But I would like to add a cover like a thumbnail over the video. wright now it is showing the starting point of video but i want an image to be there. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that would make the most sense to me is to position a div over top of the embeded video and then on click make the div not visible using jquery or javascript and then play the video

Onclick:

```
$(#Image).css("visibility","hidden");
```

Comment: Can you provide me the `jquery` code you are talking about.?

Comment: @kesarsisodiya  ya just give me a few mins to write it up